# Checking Rails 3.2.11 Installation

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am confirming a fresh ruby and rails install on a new Debian Squeeze server. Ruby responds to the version check command but rails does not. I see that the rails gem was installed but I also noticed that there is no rails install in /usr/bin/ I do see ruby in there and rake and irb.

```
-bash: rails: command not found
```

Here is the audit trail. The rails gem was installed successfully. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot would be great.

```
root@partner:~# gem1.9.1 install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.2.11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.11...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.11...

root@partners:/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems# ls
actionmailer-3.2.11    
activesupport-3.2.11     
erubis-2.7.0      
json-1.7.6         
pg-0.14.1       
rack-ssl-1.3.3   
rdoc-3.12               
treetop-1.4.12
actionpack-3.2.11      
arel-3.0.2               
fastthread-1.0.7  
mail-2.4.4         
polyglot-0.3.3  
rack-test-0.6.2  
rubygems-update-1.8.25  
tzinfo-0.3.35
activemodel-3.2.11     
builder-3.0.4            
hike-1.2.1        
mime-types-1.20.1  
rack-1.4.0      
rails-3.2.11   
sprockets-2.2.2
activerecord-3.2.11    
bundler-1.2.3            
i18n-0.6.1        
multi_json-1.5.0   
rack-1.5.1      
railties-3.2.11  
thor-0.17.0
activeresource-3.2.11  
daemon_controller-1.1.1  
journey-1.0.4     
passenger-3.0.19   
rack-cache-1.2  
rake-10.0.3      
tilt-1.3.3

root@partner:~# rails --version
-bash: rails: command not found

root@partner:~# rails-3.2.11 --version
-bash: rails-3.2.11: command not found
```

Comment: I'm not into debian but I sometimes need to do some kind of rehashing when I install gems. You might try running `$ hash -r`. More [on hash](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds2%2Fhash.htm).

Comment: Thanks. I tried rehashing but no change

Answer (score 0):

After arm wrestling with this for most of the day, I uninstalled everything, installed [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) and then installed Ruby and Rails with RVM. Much, much better.